# Trying to prevent an alert when using beforeunload. preventDefault works in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript

The below code is working in Chrome but it's not working in Firefox. Firefox is showing a popup as we leave the page as

> This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: You can't. Please search for "unbeforeunload" before posting: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unbeforeunload

Comment: Yes i have realized that when i tried to refresh the page or closing the page, that unbeforeunload event is triggering. Is there any other way to find weather the user has refreshed the page or tried to closing the page ? If so my work will be so easy.

Comment: If the window does not have the buttons "back", "refresh", "forward" then you could attach a listener on keyup event, listening for "ctrl + w" ("cmd + w" on Mac) and "ctrl + r" ("cmd + r" on Mac) or F5 key. First combination will close the window; second ones will refresh the page in it.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event):

> According to the specification, to show the confirmation dialog an
>   event handler should call preventDefault() on the event. However note
>   that not all browsers support this method...

This is a [good article](https://dev.to/chromiumdev/sure-you-want-to-leavebrowser-beforeunload-event-4eg5) about when you should use the beforeunload event. Check it out cuz you might not need it.

And here's a [polifill](https://github.com/gustavnikolaj/before-unload/) that claims to support...

> newer ES5 compatible browsers. And it should be able to support most elderly browsers if you provide them with an ES5 shim.